# Error while resizing C: drive with Gparted

Tags: windows, dual-boot, ntfs, gparted, pop-os

I have a system with Pop!_OS and Windows 10 dual booted When I was on Pop!_OS I wanted to shrink the C: drive (currently it is 400 GB) to make it about 250 GB and give the remaining to Linux. When I was doing it with gparted it showed me a error and this was the report

```
GParted 1.0.0

configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

libparted 3.3

========================================

Device: /dev/sda
Model:  ATA WDC WD5000AAKX-0
Serial: WD-WCC2EZV34735
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  976773168
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  1915241
 
Partition table:    msdos
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sda1   Primary 1126400 745105966   boot        ntfs    Drive 1 
/dev/sda2   Primary 745105968   746074671   msftres     ntfs        
/dev/sda3   Primary 746076160   950876158           ext4        /media/mint/c1220c43-fae6-47b5-9b82-fdfc64018a17
/dev/sda4   Primary 950876160   976773118           linux-swap      
========================================

Device: /dev/sdb
Model:  SanDisk Ultra
Serial: none
Sector size:    512
Total sectors:  30629376
 
Heads:  255
Sectors/track:  2
Cylinders:  60057
 
Partition table:    none
 
Partition   Type    Start   End Flags   Partition Name  File System Label   Mount Point
/dev/sdb    Unpartitioned   0   30629375            iso9660 Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon 64-bit 
========================================

Shrink /dev/sda1 from 354.76 GiB to 220.99 GiB  00:00:26    ( ERROR )
        
calibrate /dev/sda1  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )
        
path: /dev/sda1 (partition)
start: 1126400
end: 745105966
size: 743979567 (354.76 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda1 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:25    ( ERROR )
        
ntfsresize -i -f -v '/dev/sda1'  00:00:25    ( ERROR )
        
ntfsresize v2017.3.23AR.3 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda1
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 380917535232 bytes (380918 MB)
Current device size: 380917538304 bytes (380918 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
Cluster 1565940 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565941 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565942 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565943 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565944 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565945 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565946 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565947 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565948 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565949 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565950 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565951 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565952 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565953 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565954 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 1565955 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279735 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279736 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279737 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279738 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279739 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279740 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279741 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279742 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279743 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279744 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279745 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279746 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279747 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279748 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279749 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279750 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279751 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279752 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279753 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279754 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279755 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279756 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279757 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279758 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279759 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279760 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279761 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279762 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279763 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279764 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279765 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279766 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279767 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279768 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279769 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279770 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279771 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279772 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279773 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279774 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279775 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279776 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279777 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279778 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279779 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279780 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279781 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279782 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279783 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279784 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279785 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279786 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279787 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279788 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279789 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279790 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279791 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279792 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279793 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279794 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279795 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279796 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279797 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279798 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279799 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279800 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279801 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279802 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279803 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279804 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279805 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279806 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279807 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279808 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279809 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279810 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279811 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279812 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279813 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279814 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279815 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279816 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279817 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279818 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279819 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279820 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279821 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279822 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279823 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279824 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279825 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279826 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279827 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279828 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279829 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279830 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279831 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279832 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279833 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279834 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279835 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279836 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279837 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279838 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279839 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279840 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279841 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279842 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279843 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279844 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279845 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279846 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279847 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279848 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279849 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279850 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279851 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279852 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279853 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279854 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279855 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279856 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279857 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279858 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279859 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279860 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279861 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14279862 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586335 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586336 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586337 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586338 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586339 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586340 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586341 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586342 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586343 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586344 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586345 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586346 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586347 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586348 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586349 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586350 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586351 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586352 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586353 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586354 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586355 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586356 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586357 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586358 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586359 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586360 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586361 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586362 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586363 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586364 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586365 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586366 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586367 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586368 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586369 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586370 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586371 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586372 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586373 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586374 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586375 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586376 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586377 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586378 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586379 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586380 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586381 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586382 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586383 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586384 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586385 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586386 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586387 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586388 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586389 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586390 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586391 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586392 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586393 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586394 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586395 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586396 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586397 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586398 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586460 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586461 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586462 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586432 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586433 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586434 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586435 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586436 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586427 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586457 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586458 is referenced multiple times!
Cluster 14586459 is referenced multiple times!
100.00 percent completed
ERROR: Filesystem check failed!
ERROR: 220 clusters are referenced multiple times.
NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.
```

Can someone tell me why it happened and how to fix it?
And do I need to run the command it says in the bottom third line?
Please help.
*Thanks*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end of the disk check reports that,

> ```
> NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
> The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
> and will be made to NTFS by this software until it gets repaired.
> ```

Until you do this you won't be able to resize the partition.

Comment: I have the same problem, and have done the chkdsk thing several times. Almost every time I boot this thing it does a disk repair. Sometimes it doesn't need to do it for a boot or two, but will start doing it again after a few boots. Is  VirtualBox virtual machine. I'd like to make the virtual drive bigger as I'm out of space, but cannot copy or do anything with this thing due to the cluster issues. How do you find what files are affected, can we delete them if not needed to help? Is there any other tool to try as chkdsk does nto seem successful?